# the usage of "one of"

Tags: word-usage

> And then had come the unlooked-for tidings of the imminent proceedings
>   for divorce. And such a divorce! There were cross-suits and
>   allegations and counter-allegations, charges of cruelty and desertion,
>   everything in fact that was necessary to make the case **one of** the most
>   complicated and sensational of its kind.

from http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml

I think "one of" is used with "noun phrase".

e.g.  one of the most famous mountains

But in this case it is used without "noun phrase".

Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is the noun phrase:

... the most complicated and sensational of its kind

The possessive pronoun **its** refers back to "the case".

Depending on how you analyze it, in **the most complicated and [most] sensational**, the superlative adjectives are substantives, acting like nouns, or there is ellipsis of an understood plural "cases".

> The  electric car known as The Zoomer is one of the most complicated and sensational of its kind.

If you analyze it as a case of ellipsis:

> The  electric car known as The Zoomer is one of the most complicated and sensational <sup>cars</sup> of its kind.

If you analyze the adjectives as substantives by virtue of their being part of "its kind":

> The  electric car known as The Zoomer is one of the most complicated and sensational of its kind.

**its kind** would refer to the kind of the car known as the Zoomer, namely, "electric cars".

> The  electric car known as The Zoomer is one of the most complicated and sensational of electric cars.

Comment: The ellipsis analysis seems more plausible here. I take it the substantive adjective analysis would paraphrase as something like "When it comes to electric cars, the Zoomer is a prime example of the complicated", which seems like a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

It is used with a noun phrase:

> one of the most complicated and sensational of its **kind**

"Kind" is the main noun in the noun phrase.

Comment: What is the role of "of its"?

Comment: @bandaid "its" is a standard possessive pronoun. Here it means "the case's kind" as in "the case was one of the most complicated and sensational cases of all similar cases".